# How to manage Game Center Invitation custom view

Tags: game-center, invitation, gkturnbasedmatch

I am developing a Turn Based game for iPhone/iPad IOS 6. I manage my GameCenter different games of the game with my own view. It works OK. I want to know if it is possible to manage user invitations to play the game with my own view. If this is not possible I would like to know how to manage it with the Game Center custom view. I want to invite players by usermane with my game.

I read that with this method I activated the invitations:

```
- (void)registerInvites {
    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {
        self.pendingInvite = acceptedInvite;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = playersToInvite;
        [delegate inviteReceived];
    };
}
```

How can I send invitations with my own view?How can I manage the invitations that I received in my own view?How can I know if someone accept or decline my invitation?